# Chrome giving a variable set to 0 a value it shouldn't have

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, variables

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
Lifetime Earnings: $<span id="lifetimeearnings">0</span><br />
Total Clicks: <span id="demo">0</span><br />
Total Steal Earnings: $<span id="steal">0</span><br />
Total Thug Earnings: $<span id="thugEarn">0</span><br />
Total Assassin Earnings: $<span id="assassinEarn">0</span><br />
Total Drug Farm Earnings: $<span id="farmEarn">0</span><br />
Total Lawyer Earnings: $<span id="lawyerEarn">0</span><br />
Total Protection Racket Earnings: $<span id="racketEarn">0</span>
</div>
```

I have this div show statistics through span tags on my website.

```
var thugEarn = window.setInterval(function(){

thugEarn = thugEarn + thugs;

}, 1000);

var thugEarn = 0;
```

As you can see the variables should initially be set to 0. and this is the case when I run it through localhost in chrome, and when it is live in firefox. However, when it is live in chrome, all the statistics under the variable "steal" already have a value assigned to them. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: you are using the same variable named 'thugEarn' at two different places. It is also the handle for the setInterval which it should not be.

Comment: Where is `thugs` defined? Why do you use same variable identifier `thugEarn` for `setInterval()` and for `var thugEarn = 0`? What is expected result?

Comment: @NawedKhan This is working in every other browser though. What would I need to change for it to work in chrome too?

Comment: You need to show more code. There's absolutely no way to tell what's going wrong from the little bit you posted. We need to see how you're using the variables to update the spans.

Comment: Use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to post an MCVE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The stack snippet does not show the problem. The problem is only present on the live version of the site in chrome. Even when ran through localhost  using chrome it does not have the problem.

Comment: Can you post a link to the live site?

Comment: [Live site](http://crimeunderworld.esy.es/Increment%20Game/Index.html). This is the link. You'll need to click on statistics to show the problematic div.

Comment: "..the variables should initially be set to 0... however, in chrome... the statics under steal already have a value..." Uh, is that not your save/load mechanism in action? It's loading the values from a previous session?

Comment: No that's not the case. My load state is very different and is only shown when the load button is pressed

Comment: They all start at 0 when I load it, so I can't reproduce the issue. You'll need to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. (It's likely that you'll figure out the issue while creating this)

Comment: I've just tried it in an incognito window and that worked completely fine. It's just in my main browsing window.

Comment: Looks like clearing my browser history fixed it. Still no idea what the issue was